# Centering text on div (CSS)

Tags: css, alignment, pseudo-element

I'm trying to align some text to the center of a `<div>` using a pseudo element and absolute positioning.

```
color: #fff;
content: "Hello";
font-size: 500px;
opacity: 0.2;
transform: translateY(-50%);
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

It does't seem to work. Can this be achieved?
I could create an extra `<div>` but thought this was a lot neater.

Comment: You forgot to add `position: absolute`. And add `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` if you wants to make it vertically and horizontally in center.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest using `transform` as it may cause problems. Check my answer for an easier way to center the text.

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this code snippet:

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid #e4e6e8;
  line-height: 202px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>Some text.</div>
```